# Save trained model using java api in Tensorflow

Tags: java, tensorflow

Is there any way to save trained model using java api for serving by tensorserve?

I have the java code that train the model saved by python code. But searching a way to save trained model (the state of session) from java api had no result.

Also I found simple example how to train model [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/samples/languages/java/training/src/main/java/Train.java). And there I see the statement which saves checkpoint:

```
sess.runner()
      .feed("save/Const", checkpointPrefix)
      .addTarget("save/control_dependency")
      .run();
```

What is the "magic" constants like `"save/Const"`, `"save/control_dependency"`? Where I can find all the list of such constants?

Comment: Those names come from [the program that generated the graph](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/493d7a2e233fa874415062061fe0ce1aa62f2d3e/samples/languages/java/training/model/create_graph.py#L24), see also https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19348

Comment: Note that current TensorFlow Java bindings have very limited support for training. Python is the only well supported language for training now. If/when Java has full support for training, these magic constants will disappear.

Comment: @iga So then why this Java API exists at all if it cannot do such basic operation like save trained model?

Comment: @AndriiPischanski Java API exists for the serving use case. You load a trained model and run it for inference. It is fairly clean for this use case. For training, it just so happens that if the graph you loaded has all the training and saving ops still there, you can run them just like your inference nodes.